# How can I the list of all xx.php in pdfbox

Tags: pdfbox

This code is from `demo.php`

```
require_once 

dirname(__DIR__).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'PDFBox'.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'PDFBox.php';

require_once 

 dirname(__DIR__).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'PDFBox'.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'ExtractText.php';
```

It uses `PDFBox.php` and `ExtractText.php`
How can I the `List` of all `xx.php`

I am looking to get the names of the input fields and then write to the fields .

Comment: It is unclear what you're asking. Do you want a directory listing in php? Or a list of Acroform fields in a PDF file? Note that PDFBox is java, not php.

Answer (score 0):

I think I suspect you meant: you are using the two files of https://github.com/chelmertz/PDFBox-php. This is php and calls [certain command line utilities of PDFBox](https://pdfbox.apache.org/1.8/commandline.html) (and needs java too). There is no PDFBox command line utility to "get the names of the input fields and then write to the fields". However there are classes in the examples subproject: "PrintFields.java" and "SetField.java" that might do what you need. Download the sources [here](https://pdfbox.apache.org/downloads.html).